# Stickers/label Printer for Paint cans

Tags: printer, label-printer

One friend of mine, who has a Paint Industry, and he has now a pretty old sticker/labels system, wich uses some kind of weird paper that we could not find.

I'm asking if, somebody knows about some printer that can print such labels that can be used on that cans, so it has to be able to be used there, and be capable of outdoors using.

The questions here are:

1. What I'm looking for is a label printer, a sticker printer, or what? (I'm from latin america so my english isn't enought to see the differencies) and
2. Do you know about some specific brand/model of a printer wich can be used for that??

I think the stickers/labels paper used can be any wide/height, so that's not a problem, but the bigger the sticker/label it prints, the better.

Answer (score 1):

Do normal full or half sheet laser printer labels not stick well enough to the cans?
Avery specifically makes a line of labels they call [durable](http://www.google.com/products?q=durable+labels&oi=product_result_group&ct=title&resnum=4) and which you can find also called permanent labels. They're intended for items that might be outdoors sometimes and are made of polyester. The printer used would be a fairly normal laser printer.